# Optimise the 5 repetitive javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The 2 buttons scroll the DIV left and right. However, I have such 5 such scrollers and the Javascript gets repetitive. How can we optimize this?

PS: Demo version shows only 2 scrollers.

**DEMO JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lxw1bha/**

HTML

```
<div class="nav-scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row nav" id="boxSliderFirst">
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 1</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 2</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 3</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 4</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 5</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 6</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="btnLeftFirst" type="Button" value="Prev"/>
        <input id="btnRightFirst" type="Button" value="Next" />  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row nav" id="boxSliderSecond">
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 1</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 2</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 3</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 4</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 5</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 6</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input id="btnLeftSecond" type="Button" value="Prev"/>
        <input id="btnRightSecond" type="Button" value="Next" />  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c757d;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}
.card-body p {
  color: #393939;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.nav-underline .active {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343a40;
}
.nav-scroller__eighty {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

JS:

```
/* first scroller */
const boxSliderFirst = document.getElementById('boxSliderFirst');
document.getElementById("btnLeftFirst").onclick = () => {
  boxSliderFirst.scroll({
    left: boxSliderFirst.scrollLeft + boxSliderFirst.querySelector(".col-md-3").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
document.getElementById("btnRightFirst").onclick = () => {
  boxSliderFirst.scroll({
    left: boxSliderFirst.scrollLeft - boxSliderFirst.querySelector(".col-md-3").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
/* second scroller */
const boxSliderSecond = document.getElementById('boxSliderSecond');
document.getElementById("btnLeftSecond").onclick = () => {
  boxSliderSecond.scroll({
    left: boxSliderSecond.scrollLeft + boxSliderSecond.querySelector(".col-md-3").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
document.getElementById("btnRightSecond").onclick = () => {
  boxSliderSecond.scroll({
    left: boxSliderSecond.scrollLeft - boxSliderSecond.querySelector(".col-md-3").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

Comment: It looks like everything is identical except two HTML `id`s that you are selecting by. You can pull out the logic into a function that accepts two params (each respective `id`). Then invoke that function for all of your use cases

Comment: Yes, there are 5 such IDs. I'm not sure how to go about invoking the function for all the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the function and eventListener type for this example, but you could eliminate all but one function.

Why not use the `event.target` with one function run into an ***click*** ***eventListener*** within a loop to determine which button is being pressed. Then use the `event.target` to get the *relative* parent and its first child to get the *scrolling* element. This will all be *relative* to the `event.target`, no need for all those static functions.

This makes everything dynamic so as long as your structure is the same, no need for any unique ID's or extra functions. Just make sure you have the parent/child structure for the scrolling div and its buttons in place and all the same classes and values on the buttons.

***You can add any number of these HTML structured scroll blocks and they will all fire independently due to the `event.target` being the axis of getting the scrolling event and buttons.***

```js
// This class must be present on your next/previous buttons
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

// function to pass event into and get event.targets relative element
// and scroll scrolling element according to the class listed on the button
function scrollElement(e) {
  // get the parentNode (col-md-12) then its 
  // first childNode using the event.target
  let slider = e.target.parentNode.childNodes[1]
  // now use the event.target of the button to check the button being  
  // the event.target.value will work great for this
  e.target.value === "Next" ? slider.scroll({
    left: slider.scrollLeft + slider.querySelector(".col-md-3").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  }) : slider.scroll({
    left: slider.scrollLeft - slider.querySelector(".col-md-3").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

// run all buttons through a loop
button.forEach(btn => {
  // event listener for the button, pass event into listener
  btn.addEventListener('click', scrollElement)
})
```

```css
.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c757d;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}

.card-body p {
  color: #393939;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 32.3vw;
}

.nav-underline .active {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343a40;
}

.nav-scroller__eighty {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row nav">
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 1</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 2</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 3</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 4</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 5</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 6</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="Button" value="Prev" />
        <input class="btn" type="Button" value="Next" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row nav">
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 1</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 2</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 3</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 4</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 5</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 6</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="Button" value="Prev" />
        <input class="btn" type="Button" value="Next" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.